# Ajax to filter and display gallery thumbnails in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, filter, shortcode

Using a wordpress template because of tight deadlines for a small conference based site. There is an 'add staff' option and  [staff] shortcode that allows addition of conference attendees.
STaff can also be tagged by department. Unfortunately there is no way to dynamically filter the staff by department, so that only the staff of a particular department are displayed.

Ideally I'd like a select dropdown with a list of departments, that when selected would filter and display ONLY staff in that department.

The shortcode to display a particular department is simply

[staff department="DEPARTMENT_NAME" /]

Is there some generic ajax I could use that might accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For proper ajax working in wordpress you need to create ajax handlers, creating php files and including 'wp-load.php' is a bad practice, this article http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination/ will explain correct practice to use ajax.

You can send department name in the query parameter of ajax request, and use the wordpress `do_shortcode('[staff department="DEPARTMENT_NAME" /]')` in the function which will handle your ajax request. Print the html generated from `do_shortcode()` and replace the appropriate `<div>`'s html on ajax success callback.